# Getting properties dynamically from Javascript object

Tags: javascript, class

I have 2 function constructors in my javascript project. Like below

```
function Test(){
this.x = 45;
}

function S(){ 
this.y=78; 
this.f = new Test()
}
```

Now i have to access the property of 'S' on basis of type rather then by name. This is because there is a config file in my system which lists the variable to access in an object format like

```
[<Object of TYPE to create>,<Object of TYPE to access from created object>]

[S<classname>,Test<property type>]
```

Above means I have to create an Object of type `"S"` and access the `TEST` type property from created object.
So far i have been doing below

```
let s1 = new S()
s1[Object.keys(s1).filter(item=>s1[item] instanceof Test)[0]]
```

However, i am worried my Class may contain 15-20 variables of different type and doing this repetitively for every other configuration object may not be a good practice. Is there some other way that i am not looking at to make above job easier?

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking in this way. Your code works well until the types defined in your application become a larger group and you want to avoid a chain of conditioning.

Without the knowledge of how your application reads the config file, and how your object is structured, the below only works if `Test()` is under global scope.

To extract the right hand side of `instanceof` to become a variable, instead of a hardcoded function name. we can do

```
s1[Object.keys(s1).filter(item=>s1[item] instanceof eval("Test"))[0]]
```

or

```
s1[Object.keys(s1).filter(item=>s1[item] instanceof window["Test"])[0]]
```

substitute the `"Test"` literal with the configuration you read from the file.

The first method dynamic evaluates JavaScript code represented in string so it will return a  Test() function.

The second method takes the property of name "Test" defined in the window object, which is  function Test().

Comment: The config file is read as json, using http requests. However, there are certain guidelines on using eval in the code base which i assume are derived from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea